# Viewpager but not responding to clicklistener/

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a bug which I kind of know what is going on but not sure hoo to solve it.

I have a viewpager where each individual fragment also contains two more fragment -- a front side and a back side. The app is basically a flashcard app where you can swipe for the next card and when you click it it turns to the other side.

My problem: 
I have a set of radiobuttons available on both sides. If the user checks a button and clicks on the card, the card should turn, and the newly chosen radio button choice should appear on the other side of the card as well. The functionality of the buttons on both sides are the same-- i just put it on both sides so that the user can choose to change the radiobuttons no matter if he/she is on the front side or the back side of the flashcard. The part where the radiobuttons change on the other side if you pick a radiobutton only works when each card is fresh. If you scroll off the offscreenlimit and swipe back, the function does not work anymore(the radiobuttons on the other side won't automatically change to the newly selected one) . But since my offscreenlimit is 2, if you scroll to the immediate next card and then scroll back, it still works.

My listener inside of my outer fragment

```
           final ViewAnimator viewAnimator1 = (ViewAnimator) viewFlipper;
       viewAnimator1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
               ((definitionFragment) definitionFragment1).update();
               ((wordFragment) wordFragment1).update();            
               AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator1, FlipDirection.RIGHT_LEFT);
               final FragmentTransaction transaction3 = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               transaction3.detach(definitionFragment1);
               transaction3.add(R.id.fragment_definition, definitionFragment1);
               final FragmentTransaction transaction4 = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               transaction4.detach(wordFragment1);
               transaction4.add(R.id.fragment_word, wordFragment1);

           }
```

update metod:

```
public void update(){
    DatabaseHandler db1 = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
     List<VocabWord>words1 = db1.getAllVocabWords();
     switch(words1.get(pagenumber).getCategory())
        {
        case 0:
            mDefaultButton.setChecked(true);
            break;

        case 1:
            mRedButton.setChecked(true);
            break;

        case 2:
            mYellowButton.setChecked(true);
            break;


        case 3:
            mGreenButton.setChecked(true);
            break;

        }


}
```

Anyone have any idea how to approach this? Or does anyone know how to set a nonexistent offscreenpagelimit and make sure it never deletes any of the pages?

Comment: Do the the other parts of the `onClick()` method work?  If so then that means that your onClick is being fired, but your update method isn't working the way you'd like. If onClick is not being fired, then you might not be hooking up the listeners properly when a new Fragment is re-added.  The way you described the problem makes me think that there's something happening in the onPause() -> onDetach() methods which is making it such that your buttons are getting messed with. Basically, to start, double check that update() is getting called in all cases and that it's tracing the proper code path.

Comment: @Jonathan, I used the debugger to check and it seems that the onClick() method works if its "fresh" meaning that it hasn't gone off the "offscreenlimit". If I go off the screen limit and come back, the onclick() method is no longer firing. Oddly, the animation still works though.

Comment: Hmmm, okay.  At what part of the lifecycle in the outer fragment are you attaching that listener?

Comment: @Jonathan onCreateView

Comment: Interesting. I'm shooting pretty well into the dark at the moment, but have you overridden the `destroyItem` callback within your PagerAdapter? It looks like what happens in the ViewPager is that once you pass the offscreenLimit threshold Views get destroyed and then they added later via a call to instantiateItem when necessary.  Since you have no issue when the adapter is first set, I assume that your instantiateItem is solid.  However, it sounds like when you destroy items you do so in such a way that is not recovered on instantiation. More than that I'm not sure.  Sorry I can't help more :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer took me exactly 3 weeks to solve! What I did wrong is instead of detaching and adding the fragments you just simply use "replace."